# Can one test example belong to more than one class?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to write a code for a single layer perceptron from scratch , i.e. without using any library except numpy. The activation function used by me is sigmoid.

I have a training set of size 50, 2 attributes and in an attempt to simulate multiple class, I have two output nodes instead of 1 , so my input matrix is of the form 1x2 , the weight matrix is of the form 2x2 and the output matrix is 1x2.

I have used normal gradient descent for optimization. I trained the two weights that connect to the first output, and the other two weights connecting to the second output independently , i.e., since the weights for the first output are trained based on the first element of my training output , and similarly for the second output, the weights attached to it are trained based on the second element of my training output.

The training set is generated random from a normal distribution the first attribute from a normal distribution having mean 100 and S.D 75 , while the second output is from a normal dist. having mean 400 and S.D. 75. The classes are assigned alternatively, i.e. the 1st training example belongs to class 1, the next to class 0, the next to 1 and so on.

My problem is that with certain inputs that I provided repeatedly on randomly generated training sets, at times the input was classified into both the classes. From a mathematical point of view, is this possible? Can it be because my chosen training set is random? I think this is the case , but I want to be sure that mathematically it is indeed probable, and that it is not an error in my code or logic.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np


def sigmoid(x):
    #"Numerically-stable sigmoid function."
    if x >= 0:
        z = np.exp(-x)
        return 1 / (1 + z)
    else:
        z = np.exp(x)
        return z / (1 + z)
print("Number of input nodes is 2\n")

print("Number of output nodes is 2\n")

print("Stochastic Gradient descent used to avoid summing up and iterating till minima\n")

print("Activation function : Sigmoid\n")

#print("There are two attri

T_entries=[]
A_entries=[]



#design the input matrix X , the weight matrix W 

Rx=1
Cx=2 #Input vector is of size 1x2 , Weight is of size 2x2

W=np.array([[1.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0]]) #assigning initial value to weights
B=np.array([0.0,0.0]) #Assigning initial values to biases

#Training set

Rt=50
Ct=2 #10 training set. Classify between male and female . Attributes : Height>5'5" = 1 else 0 ; Weight > 60 =1 else 0

#print("Enter training set\n")
#print("Enter the attribute values in space seperate entries\n")

#Attributes
#T_entries=list(map(float, input().split()))

i=0
while i<50:
    pick=np.random.normal(100, 75,1)
    T_entries.append(pick)
    pick=np.random.normal(400, 75,1)
    T_entries.append(pick)
    i=i+1


T= np.array(T_entries).reshape(Rt, Ct)

#Annotation

#print("Enter annotations for training set\n")
Ra=50
Ca=2 #Annotations : 0 for male , 1 for female
#A_entries=list(map(float,input().split()))
i=0
pick=0
while i<50:
    pick=1-pick
    A_entries.append(pick)
    A_entries.append(1-pick)
    i=i+1

A=np.array(A_entries).reshape(Ra,Ca)

print("The random training set generated is\n")

i=0

while i < Ra:
    print(str(T[i][0])+" "+str(T[i][1])+" "+str(A[i][0])+" "+str(A[i][1])+"\n")
    i=i+1

print("Training....")

l_rate=0.05 #learning rate

i=0

while i<50:

       print("****************************************************************************************\n")
    print("Iteration: "+str(i)+"\n")
    x1=T[i][0]
    x2=T[i][1]
    y1=A[i][0]
    y2=A[i][1]
    print("The training example is: " +str(x1)+ " " +str(x2) +"\n")
    print("Corresponding annotations are : " +str(y1) +" " +str(y2) +"\n") 
    T_i=np.array([x1,x2]) #Getting the attributes
    A_i=np.array([y1,y2]) #Corresponding annotation
    f_x=np.matmul(T_i,W)+B #Compute the output to calculate the error

    print("Ultimate output for the training exmaple is :\n")

    print(f_x)
    calc=sigmoid(f_x[0])
    #print(calc)
    real=A_i[0]
    #print(real)

    print("Calculated value of y1 is " +str(calc) +" while the real value is " +str(real) +"\n")

    # w1 and w2 are responsible for out_1 and w3 and w4 for out_2

    err_out1=calc-real
    print("Error in y1 is "+str(err_out1)+"\n")
    W[0][0]=W[0][0]- l_rate*(2*err_out1*T_i[0]) #w1 modified 2*error*x1
    W[1][0]=W[1][0]- l_rate*(2*err_out1*T_i[1]) #w2 modified 2*error*x2
    B[0]=B[0]- l_rate*(2*err_out1) #b1 modified

    print("The weight matrix is \n")

    #print(W)

    calc=sigmoid(f_x[1])
    #print(calc)
    real=A_i[1]
    #print(real)

    print("Calculated value of y2 is " +str(calc) +" while the real value is " +str(real) +"\n")


    err_out2=calc-real
    print("Error in y2 is "+str(err_out2)+"\n")
    W[0][1]=W[0][1]-l_rate*(2*err_out2*T_i[0])
    W[1][1]=W[1][1]-l_rate*(2*err_out2*T_i[1])
    B[1]=B[1]-l_rate*(2*err_out2)
    print("The weight matrix is \n")
    print(W)

    i=i+1

#Testing our model

#print (W)

print("Enter x1 and x2")

Test_entries=list(map(float, input().split()))
Test=np.array(Test_entries).reshape(Rx,Cx)
print("Entered Test data is\n")
print(Test)
f=np.matmul(Test,W)+B
print(sigmoid(f[0][0]))
if sigmoid(f[0][0]) > 0.5 :
    print ("Class 1") 
else:
    print("Not Class 1")
print("\n")
print(sigmoid(f[0][1]))
if sigmoid(f[0][1]) > 0.5:
    print("Class 2")
else:
    print("Not Class 2")
```

Output on this test example:

```
Entered Test data is

[[223.  85.]]
1.0
Class 1


1.0
Class 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think - since the training data is **generated randomly**, the training will be performed **using the data the model has at that instance**(current), hence same input might be classified in either of the classes during different runs.

(hope I'm clear and did not confuse you more! :) do correct me if I've misunderstood your question)

Comment: Right. But what I am getting is the same input classified in both classes , in the same run.

Comment: oh ok got it, can you try re-running your code? because i'm getting different outputs `[[223.  85.]]
0.0
Not Class 1
# 
1.0
Class 2`

Comment: Yes, not always does this happen. I was trying with the same input for around 5 times; I did not expect it to be classified in both the classes at the same time, but I was wondering if the same input can be classified in both the classes in different run due to the random output. Turns out it is even worse.